# How to run Fortran Compiler and C compiler with full path in Linux (CentOS)

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cmake, fortran

I am trying to install a new version of OpenMolcas (this version https://gitlab.com/Molcas/OpenMolcas) in a cluster for scientific calculation that works on CentOS. The problem is that OpenMolcas needs a version higher than 4.8.0 of the GCC / gfortran compilers to work and we have 2 versions installed: 4.4.7 and 4.8.5. OpenMolcas detects version 4.4.7 by default and when I run the command "cmake ../OpenMolcas" it gives an error because it detects the oldest version.

I contacted the OpenMolcas developers and they answered the following:

"Use the unix which command to the absolute address to you C and Fortran compiler. Double check that the paths gives the correct version. The issue the command:

CC = path_to_c_compiler FC = path_to_fortran_compiler cmake path_to_the_openmolcas_source_directory"

Does anyone know how I can find out the "full path" (in linux, CentOS) of version 4.8.5 of the compilers to indicate that I want to run the command "cmake ../OpenMolcas" with the specific version 4.8.5?

In summary, I need to know how to find the full path where version 4.8.5 of the compilers is installed.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: We don't know where the binaries are installed on your cluster.  Please read your local documentation or contact your system administrators for support.

Comment: There is no way for someone not at your computer to know for sure. You could try this command `which gcc`, that will tell you where the older version of the gcc compiler is. That **might** give you a clue as to where the newer version is, for instance sometimes software is installed with the version number in the path name,  but there are no guarantees.

Comment: If you type "which gfortran" and "gfortran -v", what do you get?

Comment: Hello @roygvib thank you very much for your help. Please check the screenshot I have taken because it does not allow me to write so much in the comments: https://imgur.com/RYxCiuI

Comment: " it does not allow me to write so much in the comments" - Please, [edit] your question post and add this information into it (as **text**, not as *image*). This is how Stack Overflow works: all information relevant to the problem should be in the **question post**, not in the comments. See also [ask].

Comment: That `/opt/gcc/bin/gfortran` is the path to your 4.8.5 version of gfortran, as it says.

Comment: maybe try `CC=/opt/gcc/bin/gcc FC=/opt/gcc/bin/gfortran cmake ../OpenMolcas` ? (more info about installation seems to be here https://gitlab.com/Molcas/OpenMolcas/-/blob/master/doc/source/installation.guide/install.rst and also https://molcas.gitlab.io/OpenMolcas/sphinx/installation.guide/install.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help John, Roygvib and Scott. It worked! the command " CC=/opt/gcc/bin/gcc FC=/opt/gcc/bin/gfortran cmake ../OpenMolcas " it worked perfectly.                                                                                                                        
PD: I am sorry I did not express in the best way what my problem was, it is the first time that I make a post in this forum. I will try to edit the post and improve the structure of my question, next time I will do it much better.

Thanks a lot.